# How to keep original timezone with JodaTime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have date in String format I need to parse. The format is as following with timezone from all over the world :

```
String stringDate = "2016-04-29 12:16:49.222+04:30";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
```

It seems that `java.util.Date` doesn't accept timezone with `:` separator. So I'm trying with *Jodatime library* :

```
DateTime formattedDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).parseDateTime(stringDate);
LocalDateTime formattedDate2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).parseLocalDateTime(stringDate);
MutableDateTime formattedDate3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).parseMutableDateTime(stringDate);

System.out.println(formattedDate);
System.out.println(formattedDate2);
System.out.println(formattedDate3);
```

These lines output :

```
2016-04-29T09:46:49.222+02:00
2016-04-29T12:16:49.222
2016-04-29T09:46:49.222+02:00
```

As far as I understand the formatter modify output timezone to comply on mine (I'm in Paris, UTC+2), but **I want the output keep its original timezone**. Is it possible to do it with Jodatime library? Or should I change for another?

**Edit :**
Actually I need to get a `Date` object on which the timezone offset would be 270 (the timezone offset of the `stringDate` : 4 hour and 30 minutes) in place of 120 (my local timezone offset):

```
System.out.println(formattedDate.toDate().getTimezoneOffset()); // I expect 270 but I get 120
```

Comment: what would be your expected output? sounds like you need just to print the original string....

Comment: @joc Actually I need a `Date` object on which the `TimeZoneOffset()` whould *270* instead of 120*`. (I update my question)

Comment: `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` is deprecated since JDK 1.1 and always returns _your local timezone_ offset. To get timezone support you can use either joda's `DateTime` or java-8's `ZonedDateTime`. Which one do you prefer?

Answer (score 4):

What you missed is [`DateTimeFormatter#withOffsetParsed`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withOffsetParsed--):

> Returns a new formatter that will create a datetime with a time zone equal to that of the offset of the parsed string.

Otherwise the formatter will parse it into your local time zone (surprising, I know).

```
@Test
public void preserveTimeZone() {
    String stringDate = "2016-04-29 12:16:49.222+04:30";
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

    DateTime dt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(stringDate);

    System.out.println(dt); // prints "2016-04-29T12:16:49.222+04:30"
}
```

As for your edit - `java.util.Date` does not hold time zone information and the deprecated `getTimezoneOffset()` method only

> Returns the offset, measured in minutes, for the local time zone relative to UTC that is appropriate for the time represented by this `Date` object.

So you'd better use Joda Time or `java.time` classes to handle time zones properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the same code that you have posted, I end up with

```
2016-04-29T02:46:49.222-05:00
2016-04-29T12:16:49.222
2016-04-29T02:46:49.222-05:00
```

which if you will notice, has different hour values AND time-zone values. However, if you look at their millis:

```
System.out.println(formattedDate.getMillis());
System.out.println(formattedDate2.toDateTime().getMillis());
System.out.println(formattedDate3.getMillis());
```

you'll see the output

```
1461916009222
1461950209222
1461916009222
```

So they have the same epoch time, but are printed out differently. This is due to the mechanism of `toString()` on DateTime objects, and how they are to be interpreted.

DateTime and LocalDateTime(MutableDateTime is just a mutable version of DateTime) deal with the same epoch time in different ways. LocalDateTime will *always* assume that epoch time is UTC time(per the [javadoc for LocalDateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html)), while DateTime will assume that epoch is represented in the time zone of the Chronology which it holds(per the [javadoc again](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)). If the TimeZone is not specified at construction time, then the Chronology will assume that you want the timezone of your *default Locale*, which is set by the JVM. In your case, the default Locale is Paris France, while mine is St. Louis USA. Paris currently holds a +2:00 time zone offset, while St. Louis has -5:00, leading to the different time zone representations when we print it.

To get even more annoying, those offsets can change over time. If I come back in 6 months and try to answer this again, my values will show -6:00 (stupid Daylight savings time!)

The important thing to remember is that these two dates have the same *epoch time*: we are talking about the same instant in time, we are just representing that time differently when we print it out.

If you want to use a different time zone for representing the *output* of the parse result, then you can set the DateTimeZone during formatting using `DateTimeFormat.withZone()` or `DateTimeFormat.withLocale`:

```
DateTimeFormatter sdf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes(4,30));
System.out.println(formattedDate.getMillis());
System.out.println(formattedDate2.toDateTime().getMillis());
System.out.println(formattedDate3.getMillis());
```

which will print

```
2016-04-29 12:16:49.222+0430
2016-04-29 12:16:49.222
2016-04-29 12:16:49.222+0430
```

notice that the LocalDateTime version still prints out without the TimeZone. That's kind of the feature of LocalDateTime: it is represented without having to deal with all this business.

So that is why your printing values look weird. To further your question about getting a `java.util.Date` object from the parsed DateTime object: `toDate` will give you a `java.util.Date` which represents the same epoch time. However, `java.util.Date` behaves similarly to `DateTime`, in that unless otherwise stated, it will use the TimeZone of the default Locale. If you know the Locale ahead of time, then you can use the `toDate(Locale)` method to ensure you use that Locale's TimeZone offset.

It gets a lot harder if you don't know the TimeZone ahead of time; in the past, I've had to hand-parse the TimeZone hour and minute offsets to determine the proper TimeZone to use. In this *exact* case that's not too difficult, since the last 6 characters are extremely well-formed and regular(unless, of course, they aren't :)).